# What file is being moved in applescript

Tags: terminal, applescript

Good Day.

I have a basic applescript that is moving the oldest file from one folder to another. I'm running the applescript from the command line:

`osascript /Users/dmayo/Documents/scripts/MoveOldest.scpt`

I'm also having the script stdout to the terminal, but can't seem to reference just the filename. Here's what I get at the line in code `log this_item`:

```
«class docf» 2016-04-12-01-31-31.pdf of «class cfol» 2013-long of «class cfol» Scans of «class cfol» dmayo of «class cfol» Users of «class sdsk»
```

I'd like just the file name "2016-04-12-01-31-31.pdf" on each line of the output. Here's my Applescript:

---

```
repeat
    tell application "Finder"
        set src to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:dmayo:Scans:2013-long"
        set dest to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:dmayo:Scans"
        set sorted_list to sort items of src by creation date
        set this_item to item 1 of sorted_list
        move item 1 of sorted_list to dest
        log this_item
    end tell
    delay 120
end repeat
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just log the `name` of the item

Edit: As `log` does not belong to the Finder move it out of the Finder tell block

```
repeat
    tell application "Finder"
        set src to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:dmayo:Scans:2013-long"
        set dest to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:dmayo:Scans"
        set sorted_list to sort items of src by creation date
        set this_item to item 1 of sorted_list
        move this_item to dest
        set fileName to name of (this_item as alias)
    end tell
    log fileName
    delay 120
end repeat
```

Comment: Nope. The stdout in the terminal results in:
`name of «class docf» 2016-04-12-01-31-31.pdf of «class cfol» 2013-long of «class cfol» Scans of «class cfol» dmayo of «class cfol» Users of «class sdsk»`

Comment: Nope. Same long output.

Comment: Strange. You're logging `fileName` not `this_item`? What happens with `set fileName to name of (this_item as alias)`

Comment: Bingo. Thanks. Where'd I find documentation on the parenthesis?

Comment: Parentheses are used in the same way as in arithmetics to encapsulate an expression. I guess it's covered in [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html)